# Why would the variable be recognised as a number in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/LukeXF/pen/XJJGmw)**

I am trying to make a simple part of the site that the allows the user to plus or minus a button to show or take away more HTML elements.

However I can effectively do that by setting a number. But it does not work when I use the value of the input box. This input box can be added or subtracted depending on the button clicked and that part works fine.

**HTML:**

```
<p>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" id="minus2" width="20" height="20" class="minus"/>
  <input id="qty2" type="text" value="1" class="qty"/>
  <img id="add2" src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" width="20" height="20" class="add"/>
</p>

<div class="thisdiv"></div>
<div class="thisdiv"></div>
<div class="thisdiv"></div>
<div class="thisdiv"></div>
<div class="thisdiv"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thisdiv {
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  float:left; 
  clear:both; 
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
  // Automatically hide all the thumbnails
  $('.thisdiv').hide();

  // When the add button is clicked
  $('.add').on('click',function(){
    // Find the nearest value of p and set qty to equal the value in the input box
    var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
    // Set variable currentVal to the new value of the qty
    var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
    // If the current value is a number then add one.
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
    }
    // Return debug message
    console.log("ADDED ONE. VALUE NOW: " + (currentVal + 1));

    // This should set the number of divs to display to the 
    // value of currentVal, but it does not work?

    $('.thisdiv:lt(currentVal)').show();
  });

  // When the minus button is clicked
  $('.minus').on('click',function(){
    // Find the nearest value of p and set qty to equal the value in the input box
    var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
    // Set variable currentVal to the new value of the qty
    var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
    // If the current value is more than 0 and is a number then minus one
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      $qty.val(currentVal - 1);            
    }
    // Return debug message
    console.log("SUBTRACTED ONE. VALUE NOW: " + (currentVal - 1));

    // This should set the number of divs to display to the 
    // value of currentVal, but it does not work?
    $('.thisdiv:lt(currentVal)').show();
  });
});
```

If you replace the currentVal with a real number it works to display the number
But that's not dynamic like how I want. Why wouldn't the currentVal work?
The example here works `$('.thisdiv:lt(2)').show();` whereas `$('.thisdiv:lt(currentVal)').show();` does not even though currentVal is a valid number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.thisdiv:lt(currentVal)').show();` doesn't use the variable `currentVal` at all, it just has the literal text `'currentVal'` as part of your selector string. Try this instead:

```
$('.thisdiv:lt(' + currentVal + ')').show();
```

This concatenates the shorter string `'.thisdiv:lt('` with the value of the variable `currentVal` and with the short string`')'` on the end.

Note that you already seem to know this, because you've used the same principle in the following line of your code:

```
console.log("SUBTRACTED ONE. VALUE NOW: " + (currentVal - 1));
```

Comment: Fantastic, fixed the issue. What a stupid mistake to make on my behalf.

Comment: The issue now is the demo works on the adding. But not the subtractions. Any idea why?

Comment: The demo link in your question seems to work fine for adding and subtracting (but perhaps you've updated it since your comment four hours ago).

Comment: That's correct.. I simply set when the minus button is clicked to hide all then display the correct currentVal. So rather than actually taking a value away, it just resets and applies the correct number. 
Anyway, cheers for the help. This works very nicely integrated into my project.